# SSL with custom user domains

Tags: http, ssl, heroku, http-status-code-301

I am building an eCommerce platform and I would like to give my user's the ability to point their domain (e.g. bobsburgers.com) to an HTTPS-protected subdomain on my site (e.g. bobsburgers.shoplolz.com). Getting a wildcard certificate for the dynamic subdomain is simple, but how does one allow their users to use their own domain while requiring HTTP? I'm currently hosted on Heroku but I'm curious at a higher level how this can work, if at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my research the only way to do this is to have the site owner upload an SSL certificate and use an HTTPS-enabled reverse proxy which can be configured dynamically to accept new SSL certificates for newly added domains.

Comment: This is unfortunate! Have you found a better way since? What about using Let's Encrypt?